# Using a Reference Table Service in a WPF Application

Tags: wpf, architecture, reference

For past projects(the last few have been web using asp.net mvc) we created a service that caches our reference tables(as required) to be used primarily for dropdown lists.

Now I'm working on a desktop application.An upgrade from vb6/sybase to vb.net/sql server

I'm trying out WPF.

I started down the same path building up my DAL. one entity for each reference table.

I'm at the stage now where I want to setup the business layer (some reference tables can be edited)

And I'm not sure if I should follow the same process which is to use  ReferenceTableService to "manage" the reference tables.(interacts with the DAL, Controller)

This will be an application that sits on a share that multiple users run.

What's the best way to deal with the reference tables? Caching them doesn't seem to be an option. Should I simply load them as each user opens up a new form in the application? Perhaps using a "ReferenceTableService"?

In this case, the Reference Table Service is thin layer in the application. Not a process running elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done much WPF (be interesting to see what the WPF Gurus think) but I think your existing approach is sound and I don;t see why you should deviate from it.

Loading up on app start sounds reasonable; you just have to think about the expected lifetime of a user session vs the expected frequency of changes to the reference data.

Caching: if the data comes from a central service you could always introduce caching there.

Comment: thx AK. I decided to stick with the same approach (minus the caching)